# Best data structure to implement a voting system

Tags: data-structures

I need to design a voting system on a high level that associates voters with their decision in sorted order by name.

I understand that I should implement a sorted map, and it seems like we need a map that performs best with random insertions. So I was wondering which of the above data structures would work best.

Comment: Which language are you using, how are you getting input, and how are you showing output? If you've already decided a map would work best, many languages already have maps / dictionaries built in.

Comment: No particular language, just a theoretical question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sorting the objects based purely by name, I would say that a Binary Search Tree would work well.

If you are particularly worried about search time complexity, you can implement a balanced tree, such as an AVL tree or a splay tree. Doing this would get your search time complexity towards logarithmic, which is what you're after!

Answer (score 1):

A heap or a BST. Trie linked list and array would have a higher search complexity.